# Prove that P (A ∪ B) = P (A) ∪ P(B) is true iff B ⊆ A or A ⊆ B.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that P (A ∪ B) = P (A) ∪ P(B) is true iff B ⊆ A or A ⊆ B.

I know that in **general**, P (A ∪ B) = P (A) ∪ P(B) is not true (thus the iff is needed here).

I'm having trouble proving it formally.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is P?  Is it the power set?  In any event, the way to show two sets are equal is to show that every element of the left-hand side is an element of the right-hand side, and vice versa.

Comment: @saulspatz Yes, most likely.

Comment: Consider the non-trivial part: if $P (A ∪ B) = P (A) ∪ P(B)$, then either $B ⊆ A$ or $A ⊆ B$. Assume $P (A ∪ B) = P (A) ∪ P(B)$ and **not** ($B ⊆ A$ or $A ⊆ B$).

Comment: Find a subset of $A\cup B$ that is not a subset of either A nor of B.

Comment: hint for $C \subset A\cup B$ to *not* be a subset of A it needs an element not in A.  For C to not be a subset of B it needs an element not in B.  When can such elements always be found and when can they not be found.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a \in A \setminus B$ and $b \in B \setminus A$.  Then $\{a,b\}\in P(A\cup B)$ but $\{a,b\} \not \in P(A)$ and $\{a,b\} \not \in P(B)$.

And if $A \subset B$ then $A\cup B = B$ and $P(A) \cup P(B) = P(B)$.

====

I suppose proving that $X \subset Y \implies P(X) \subset P(Y)$ requires a bit of thought.  But not too much.

Comment: First of all thank you for the answer. I understand both first and second lines of the proof but I'm having trouble with understanding the connection (or rather, the transition) between the two. Are both needed to prove, or I can start by the second one, show it that it's true for if B ⊂ C and be done with?

Comment: The first line is a proof of the contrapositive:  If neither $A \subset B$ nor $B \subset A$ then $P(A)\cup P(B) \ne P(A\cup B)$.  And therefore if $P(A)\cup P(B) = P(A\cup B) \implies A\subset B$ or $B\subset A$.  The second line is a hint for the other direction.  If $A\subset B$ then $A\cup B=B$ and $P(A\cup B)=P(B)=P(A)\cup P(B)$.  It's a hint that needs to be fleshed out.

Comment: "The same argument will apply if $B \subset A$" of "If $A \subset B$ or $B\subset A$, and without loss of generality, we'll assume $A\subset B$" are both acceptable arguments to use in standard proofs.  Depends on the rigor required (not likely that high).

Comment: Very clear answer, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If $\wp(A\cup B)=\wp(A)\cup\wp(B)$ then from $A\cup B\in\wp(A\cup B)$ it follows that: $$A\cup B\in\wp(A)\cup\wp(B)$$ so that: $$A\cup B\in\wp(A)\text{ or }A\cup B\in\wp(B)$$ or equivalently: $$A\cup B\subseteq A\text{ or }A\cup B\subseteq B$$ or equivalently: $$B\subseteq A\text{ or }A\subseteq B$$

Comment: In a formal proof, do I have to split cases? For example after the "A∪B∈℘(A) or A∪B∈℘(B)" line?

Comment: You can do that, but also you can maintain "or" in these rules.

Comment: Can you explain why $A\cup B\in\wp(A)\text{ or }A\cup B\in\wp(B)$ implies $A\cup B\subseteq A\text{ or }A\cup B\subseteq B$? I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around that.

Comment: @Yaya123 In my answer answer $\wp(A)$ denotes the power set of $A$, that is the set that has all subsets of $A$ as elements. So $A\cup B\in\wp(A)$ means exactly that $A\cup B$ is a subset of $A$, that is $A\cup B\subseteq A$. Same story for $B$.